# How should i design my ViewModel and save it using AutoMapper and EF?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

Im not quite sure how to use ViewModels so i need some help on the following issue:

I am creating a online survey. 
A user is able to create a multiple choice question. The domain entities that i use for this to happen are the following:

```
[Question]
int category_id { get; set; } // The category the question belongs to
int type_code { get; set; } // The type of question (I.E Multiple Choice)
string question_wording { get; set; } // The question itself
bool visible { get; set; } // Visiblity
int question_number { get; set; } // The number of the question
string help_text { get; set; } // Help text if the user doesnt understand the question

[Multiple_Choice_Question]
int choice_number { get; set; } // The order in which the MCQ answer possibility is shown
int choice_wording { get; set; } // The MCQ answer possibility
string help_text { get; set; } // help_text if the user doesnt understand the answer possibility

// This is a cross-reference table in my database that maps questions with choice possibilities

[Ref_Multiple_ChoiceAnswer]
int question_id { get; set; }
int mcq_id { get; set; }
```

In my View i need to be able to create the question and the choice possibilities (Multiple_Choice_Question) at the same time. The user writes the choice possibilties in a textbox, each seperated by a new line.

like

```
Cat
Dog
Mouse
```

Now that im working with two entities should i just put all the necessary properties in my ViewModel? Each Answer possibility is a new row in my database, and in the View it gets sent back as a string (the text in the textbox) - how do i solve this?

How do i use AutoMapper on [HttpPost] to bind the properties from the Question with a new Question Object and the answer possibilities with a Multiple_Choice_Question Object. Also, what is the best way to map theese two new entities in the Ref_Multiple_ChoiceAnswer table?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to bind props from view model. It`s so by design.

This drives design more towards oop.
State of Your model should be changed through invoked behavior.

E.g. instead of:

```
question.visible=questionViewModel.visible;
```

You should be using:

```
class QuestionController{
 ActionResult Hide(int question){
   var q=find(question);
   q.Hide();
   return q.As<QuestionViewModel>();

 }
}
class Question{
  void Hide(){
    Visible=false;
  }
}
```

That is why "binding properties" kind a makes no sense.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. It isnt exactly the answer i was looking for, but as you are the only one who answered so i will mark it as an answer.

Comment: @Nanek http://bit.ly/p8shJh was retweeted by Jimmy - author of Automapper himself :)